# How to change the review tab title in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, tabs, product-review

I have attempted to create a module that would allow me to change the review tab title on the product page, the change isn't taking effect so I must be missing something. Any help is appreciated.

> Custom/Review/etc/module.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
         <module name="Custom_Review" setup_version="1.0.0" />
    </config>
```

> Custom/Review/Block/Product/Review.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Custom\Review\Block\Product;

use Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

/**
 * Product Review Tab
 *
 * @author     Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Review extends Template implements IdentityInterface
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    /**
     * Review resource model
     *
     * @var \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_reviewsColFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->_reviewsColFactory = $collectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);

        $this->setTabTitle();
    }

    /**
     * Get current product id
     *
     * @return null|int
     */
    public function getProductId()
    {
        $product = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('product');
        return $product ? $product->getId() : null;
    }

    /**
     * Get URL for ajax call
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getProductReviewUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl(
            'review/product/listAjax',
            [
                '_secure' => $this->getRequest()->isSecure(),
                'id' => $this->getProductId(),
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Set tab title
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setTabTitle()
    {
        $title = $this->getCollectionSize()
            ? __('The Reviews %1', '<span class="counter">' . $this->getCollectionSize() . '</span>')
            : __('The Reviews');
        $this->setTitle($title);
    }

    /**
     * Get size of reviews collection
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getCollectionSize()
    {
        $collection = $this->_reviewsColFactory->create()->addStoreFilter(
            $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
        )->addStatusFilter(
            \Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED
        )->addEntityFilter(
            'product',
            $this->getProductId()
        );

        return $collection->getSize();
    }

    /**
     * Return unique ID(s) for each object in system
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getIdentities()
    {
        return [\Magento\Review\Model\Review::CACHE_TAG];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `etc/di.xml` which is necessary to rewrite `setTabTitle()` method.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Review\Block\Product\Review" type="Custom\Review\Block\Product\Review" />
</config>
```

And your `Custom\Review\Block\Product\Review.php` should look like this:

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Review\Block\Product;

class Review extends \Magento\Review\Block\Product\Review
{
    /**
     * Set tab title
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setTabTitle()
    {
        $title = $this->getCollectionSize()
            ? __('The Reviews %1', '<span class="counter">' . $this->getCollectionSize() . '</span>')
            : __('The Reviews');
        $this->setTitle($title);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

override catalog_product_view.xml in your custom module/theme and add this code to change the tab title.

```
        <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Ratings and Review</argument>
                </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </referenceBlock>
```